# Unable to install PyRFC

Tags: python, saprfc, pyrfc

I would like to install pyrfc but the package doesn't seem to exist anymore:

```
C:\>easy_install pyrfc-1.9.3-py2.7-win32.egg
Searching for pyrfc-1.9.3-py2.7-win32.egg
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyrfc-1.9.3-py2.7-win32.egg/
Couldn't find index page for 'pyrfc-1.9.3-py2.7-win32.egg' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for pyrfc-1.9.3-py2.7-win32.egg
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pyrfc-1.9.3-py2.7-win32.egg')
```

I have also searched the site https://pypi.python.org/simple/, no success, there is no such thing like pyrfc. I have tried with pip but no luck either.
Does pyrfc still exist?
Any obvious mistakes in what I'm doing?
Thx

Answer (score 1):

get it from github

https://github.com/SAP/PyRFC/tree/master/dist

and use easy_install

C:\myprograms>easy_install C:\Users*****\PyRFC\dist\pyrfc-1.9.4-py2.7-win-amd
64.egg

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/SAP/PyRFC

**A prerequisite to download is having a customer or partner account on SAP Service Marketplace** and if you are SAP employee please check SAP OSS note 1037575 - Software download authorizations for SAP employees.

If you press on "Download" in this link http://sap.github.io/PyRFC/install.html - you'll be asked for username/password

Comment: This only applies to the RFC DLL from SAP. I *have* that DLL. I'm missing the python part. The python part has nothing to do with SAP as far as I can see.

Comment: Did you check for the python code in the following git : https://github.com/SAP/PyRFC ?

Comment: @kaidentity If I answered your question, please accept it.

Comment: Yes I did check the code but it didn't look promising. I'm not looking for a source code repo with some code in it, I'm looking for installable packages.

Answer (score 0):

did you try pip install pyrfc?
it works for me